# I can't update Django's RedirectView. It keeps referring to the old URL with a status of 301 Moved Permenantly

Tags: django, apache, http-status-code-301, django-class-based-views

Sorry if this question was supposed to be in Server Vault. I couldn't really tell whether it's a programming error or a server configuration error.

I recently pushed my git commits to the live server and I noticed something very frustrating.

No matter how I edit the `urls.py`, I can't seem to update `RedirectView`!

Here is my root `mysite/urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(url=reverse_lazy('order_list')), name='home'),
    url(r'^doors/', include('doors.urls')),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^{}/'.format(settings.DAJAXICE_MEDIA_PREFIX), include('dajaxice.urls')),
)
```

The named URL `order_list` comes from one of my app's `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = patterns('doors.views',
    url(r'^order/$', OrderListView.as_view(), name='order_list'),
    # And more URL patterns...
)
```

So basically I simply changed `r'^orders/$'` to `r'^order/$'` in the last commit. But whenever I do `{% url home %}`, I noticed the server keeps trying to redirect to the **old** path of `/doors/orders/` instead of `/doors/order/`. I also noticed that the redirect is a `301 Moved Permanently`.

So I tried to add `permenant=False` to `RedirectView` and restarted the server. But it *still* goes to `/doors/orders/` and the redirect is still `301` (it should have been `302`)!

Why isn't my `RedirectView` redirecting to the updated URL?

---

**Server info**

Running Apache 2.2.21 using mod_wsgi with Django 1.4 on Gentoo Linux

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It turned out that the `301` redirections are cached on the **browser**!

So I cleared my browser's cache and everything worked. It was hard knowing where to look for the error when I didn't really understand the difference between `301` and `302` that well. I also realized that since my `RedirectView` is basically a placeholder until I write a real home template. I should be using `permanent=False` to always create a `302`. Take a look at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.RedirectView.permanent) for details.