# Django auto redirecting to url folder of a different project

Tags: python, django

My current project url file redirects empty urls to a certain app folder

new_project/url.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.views.generic import RedirectView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    url(r'^new_app/', include('new_app.urls')), 
    url(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/new_app/', permanent=True)),
]
```

I have another older project which uses a similar urlpattern:
old_project/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/old_app/', permanent=True)),
]
```

But when I try to open the new project site(www.new_project.com/), I get a 404 error. The error says the urlpatterns are being compared with a the old project string (old_app/)

Error page:

```
Using the URLconf defined in new_project.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

1. ^admin/
2. ^accounts/
3. ^new_app/
4. ^$


The current path, old_app/, didn't match any of these.
```

All my projects are using the same redirect folder. I am guessing this has something to do with how I have used `permanet=True`. Why is this happening and how can this be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to clear your browser cache completely, it should work.

See that [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10513470/i-cant-update-djangos-redirectview-it-keeps-referring-to-the-old-url-with-a-s).

Answer (score 0):

If both projects use the same dependencies and are in the same directory structure, you need to import your `old_project` urls into `new_project/url.py` file and add the old urls into `urlpatterns` list.

If they have different dependencies, then everything is in your deployment configuration. Web server should be configured to run one or another project depending on what url the client ask for. How to do it changes a lot depending on your infrastructure, web server, etc. so you would need to be more specific.

Comment: Same dependencies and same directory structure. Can you show an example please?